# Using partitioning and clustering fields in Google BigQuery

Tags: database-design, google-bigquery, database-schema

I am working with some historic CRM data for multiple clients. I arrange my BigQuery schema to have the following format:

`PARTITION_MONTH (DATE) | CLIENT_UUID (STR) | PDATE (Date) | ...`

I make my partition field have month granularity via truncating `PDATE` to compensate for BQ's current 4k partition limit. In addition, I have `CLIENT_UUID` set as a clustered field to speed up client-specific queries. Doing some benchmarking, I noticed `PARTITION_MONTH` has no affect on how many bytes are scanned.

The client I tested with accounts for 37% of the records in my table. I have three tables (identical data) where one has partitioning/clustering, clustering with all partitions set to NULL, and no partitioning/clustering. A simple aggregate sum on the clustered tables show the `CLIENT_UUID` clustering is working:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM dataset.table WHERE CLIENT_UUID='myclient'

Non-Partitioned:       513 MB processed
Clustered:             191 MB processed (~37% of non-partitioned)
Partitioned/Clustered: 191 MB processed
```

However, when I incorporate the date in the query, the partitioned field shows no performance gain:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM dataset.table
WHERE CLIENT_UUID='myclient'
  AND [PARTITION_MONTH/PDATE] > DATE(2000, 1, 1)

Non-Partitioned:       513 MB processed
Clustered:             191 MB processed (~37% of non-partitioned)
Partitioned/Clustered: 191 MB processed
```

I would assume underneath the hood, BigQuery would simply ignore all partitions prior to the specified date. However, it appears it's scanning all of the client's rows.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is it a matter of BigQuery or perhaps the way I'm structuring my queries? Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Try this from manual `Express the predicate filter as closely as possible to the table identifier. Complex queries that require the evaluation of multiple stages of a query in order to resolve the predicate (such as inner queries or subqueries) will not prune partitions from the query.` which means putting the partition filter first in the where clause.

Comment: Do you have data previous to the year 2000?

Comment: I do have data prior to 2000. Tried rearranging it so the date clause was first but still getting the same results.

Comment: What is [PARTITION_MONTH/PDATE]? If you use some functions over the partitioning field then partition pruning might not work. We can look further if you can share the job id.

Comment: @HuaZhang They are both equivalent datetime fields with month granularity. PARTITION_MONTH being the partitioned field in the partition table, and PDATE being a non-partitioned field. There is no different in performance when using one or the other.

Comment: If PARTITION_MONTH is the partitioned field then we should be able to use it to prune the unqualified partitions. Again if you can proved a job id we can investigate further.

Comment: Some insights that may help here : https://medium.com/@padmanav.agarwal/big-query-partition-and-clustering-ca75187891d1